# How to replace <input text box> with a <div> filled with CSS?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

This is my first time asking a question on Stack Overflow, forgive me if I mess up the formatting. I'm trying to replace an input password box with a  with class=accessGranted CSS. When a user types into the input box and presses enter it should replace the input box with a  with CSS .accessGranted.

It should replace the input password box with ACCESS GRANTED in green letters. Also I can't figure out how to get rid of the ACCESS GRANTED that automatically shows up on the page. The JSFiddle link will show  you what I am talking about.

HTML:

```
     <body>

       <input class="passwordPress" type="password" />
       <div class="accessGranted"></div>

     </body>
```

CSS:

```
    .accessGranted:before {
        font-size: 20px;
        color: #4eff73;
        font: sans serif;
        margin-top: 200px;
        margin-left: 200px;
        display: block;
        content: "ACCESS GRANTED";
     }







    body {
      background-color: #000;
    }

   .passwordPress {
      margin-top: 200px;
      margin-left: 200px;

    }
```

JQuery:

```
   $('.passwordPress').bind("enterKey",function(e){
          alert("Enter");
                });
         $('.passwordPress').keypress(function(e){
         if(e.keyCode == 13)
           {
        $(this).replaceWith('<div class="accessGranted"></div>');
      }
     });
```

Here is a link to JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/x7HVQ/606/

Comment: What are you trying to achieve??

Comment: If you look in the JSFiddle example you will see in the results box that there is a input field for a password and then towards the bottom it says ACCESS GRANTED in green. When the user presses enter, I want the input field to disappear and the ACCESS GRANTED to take its place.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How to get rid of the ACCESS GRANTED that automatically shows up on
>   the page:

Just remove the `<div>` in `html` body

```
<body>

<input class="passwordPress" type="password" />
<!--<div class="accessGranted"></div> -->

</body>
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/x7HVQ/609/)

Comment: Hahaha. I was so close. I feel really dumb. haha Thank you so much for your help. If you can't tell, I am super new at this. Thanks again.

Comment: Everyone start up from fresh. Good luck and have fun.

Answer (score 0):

Changed a bit of the HTML to get rid of the unwanted text.

And I changed the jquery function to use e.which instead (better browser support I think)

```
e.which==13
```

http://jsfiddle.net/emj6L/

Comment: Thanks! I thought that I tried it without the <div> HTML, and it didn't work. Maybe it was pre display block in the CSS area. Thanks again.